# linux permission move_uploaded_file

Tags: file, permissions, copy, fedora

i work on linux-fedora 18 and the function move_uploaded_file show warning:

error:

```
[Wed Jun 05 18:41:21.731524 2013] [:error] [pid 11502] [client 127.0.0.1:40340] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/estampa/management/include/1.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/estampa/management/include/sys_content.php on line 31, referer: estampa/management/sistema/?secc=noticias&oper=mod&id=22
[Wed Jun 05 18:41:21.731547 2013] [:error] [pid 11502] [client 127.0.0.1:40340] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpH5BLGD' to '/var/www/html/estampa/management/include/1.jpg' in /var/www/html/estampa/management/include/sys_content.php on line 31, referer: estampa/management/sistema/?secc=noticias&oper=mod&id=22
```

php script:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
if($archivo != ""){
$target_path = "../../../web/images/pub/";
$target_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']); 
if($error_up = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
$var = "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']). " ha sido subido";
} 
else{
$var = "Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
}
}

#ls -lrt |grep include
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 May 26 15:58 include
# chmod 0777 -R include
# chown apache:apache include


httpd.conf
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    httpd.conf
    Options  -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and the function copy(), same error

can you help me, pls!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have a SELinux permissions problem. See http://albertech.net/2011/03/fix-fedora-selinux-permissions-for-php-file-upload/ for details.

Comment: finally works!! thanks asmecher, set permissions chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t folder, and view ls -halZ